# Web3j, how to correctly byte encode multiple data?

Tags: solidity, web3j, java

I am interacting with a smart contract and i do not understand correctly how to encode the data using Web3j to interact with the smart contract since I had never interacted with a contract that required multiple byte-encoded data.

//this is a small example of what i have

//Solidity example contract

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract example {

function exampleFunction(bytes memory params){

    //Decode Data.
    (address[] memory array0, uint numberExample, address[] memory array1) = abi.decode(params, (address[], uint, address[]));
    
    //do more...

  }
}
```

//Web3j

//prepare example data

```
List<String> array0 = new ArrayList<String>();
array0.add("0x......");
array0.add("0x......");

BigInteger numberExample = new BigInteger("4234242342424");

List<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
array1.add("0x......");
array1.add("0x......");
```

//this is my problem as it is my first time sending encoded data.

```
byte[] params = ????;
```

//how to correctly encode the data?

//load contract

```
MixExecutor Contract = example.load(exampleContractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit);
```

//Execute function

```
TransactionReceipt Tx = Contract.exampleFunction(params).sendAsync().get();

String hash = Tx.getTransactionHash();
```

//Contract Wrap

```
public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> exampleFunction(byte[] params) {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_EXAMPLEFUNCTION, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.DynamicBytes(params),
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
}
```

//I tried this but when executing the smart contract it gave an error.

```
String data = Arrays.<Type>asList(
        //array0
            new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.DynamicArray<org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address>(
                org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address.class,
                org.web3j.abi.Utils.typeMap(
                    array0, org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address.class
                )
            ),
        ///numberExample
            new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(numberExample),
        //array1
            new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.DynamicArray<org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address>(
                org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address.class,
                org.web3j.abi.Utils.typeMap(
                    array1, org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address.class
                )
            )
).toString();


byte[] params = data.getBytes();
```

[I think this might help me, I'll keep looking.](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/abi/src/main/java/org/web3j/abi/TypeEncoder.java)

I wonder if I will have to change the smart contract so that instead of receiving a data bytes it receives a Struct.

Answer (score 0):

```js
web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(
  ['address[]', 'uint256', 'address[]'],
  [
    ['0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD', '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD'],
    '14',
    ['0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD'],
  ]
);
```

You can read more about it in the docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html

There's also `encodeFunctionCall` to encode a full function with parameters.